# Understanding groupby after repartition in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

For the code below:

```
data1 = [(i,random.randint(1,5),random.randint(1,5)) for t in range(2) for i in range(3)]
df1=spark.createDataFrame(data1,schema = 'a int,b int,c int')
df1 = df1.repartition(4,'a')
df1.groupby('a').agg(F.max(col('b'))).explain()
```

the explain output is:

```
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- HashAggregate(keys=[a#3629], functions=[max(b#3630)])
   +- HashAggregate(keys=[a#3629], functions=[partial_max(b#3630)])
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(a#3629, 4), REPARTITION_BY_NUM, [id=#5232]
         +- Project [a#3629, b#3630]
            +- Scan ExistingRDD[a#3629,b#3630,c#3631]
```

Why do we have `HashAggregate(keys=[a#3629], functions=[partial_max(b#3630)])` in the physical plan? Shouldn't `partial_max` run on the map side? Essentially, `groupby` would compute partial sums and then all partial sums are collected and summed for each key, that is if the dataframe is not repartitioned. But, since I have repartitioned the data, what is the need for partial sums?